# discord.py defining "ctx" without parameters

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot that checks a channel, if someone send a message to this channel, their message will deleted and another channel will be open. The code is like that:

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == 727570110432280678:
        await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
        guild = ctx.message.guild
        overwrites = {
            guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
            guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
            ctx.guild.roles[2]: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
            ctx.message.author: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
        }
        await ctx.guild.categories[2].create_text_channel(name='test', overwrites=overwrites)
```

But I have to define "ctx" and I don't know how. When i type it in

```
async def on_message(ctx, message):
```

I get  missing 1 required positional argument error, so I have to define it on code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ctx object is often not required. Events give you all the objects you will need to.
The object you get from events often have other data in them such as guild objects and more (just read the documentation).

In this case you have a [message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_messag#discord.Message) object from the [on_message() event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_messag#discord.on_message).
It is recommended to look up in the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to see what you can do with it.
When you read the documentation about the [message object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_messag#discord.Message) you will see that it has a [guild object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_messag#discord.Message.guild).

Now you can do this:

```
guild = message.guild
```

to retrieve the guild object you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `guild = ctx.message.guild` with `guild = message.guild`. You can get the `guild` from the `message` object.